# Excel: Computing Regular Deposits for a Specified Future Amount

Tags: excel, accounting

I had tried to run some example from my calculator on excel. I cannot get the correct answer of 203.13. Can someone try to pinpoint the error in my formula?

You plan to open a savings account and deposit the same amount of money at the beginning of each month. In 10 years, you want to have $25,000 in the account.
How much should you deposit if the annual interest rate is 0.5% with quarterly compounding?

```
FV      25000
NPER    10
RATE    0.50%

PMT ($193.23)

=PMT(RATE/4, NPER*12,,FV)
```

Comment: The answer you write, of $203.13, would be correct with monthly compounding and monthly payments.  It is difficult to understand how the answer would be the same for quarterly compounding with monthly payments.

Answer (score 0):

You must observe consistency in the periodicity. If you use monthly payments, you must have an NPER in months as well, and a monthly RATE. THe difficulty here is that the quarterly compound with a monthly deposit.
If you calculate everything on a quarterly basis, you will also have dfferences, but I think they will be minor.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate a precise answer you would need to know when you made the first payment relative to the bank's quarterly interest cycle.  If your first deposit was immediately before the interest compound date, interest would start accruing immediately.  If your first deposit was immediately after the interest compound date, interest would not accrue immediately.

Also the bank may calculate interest based on the ending balance or on the average balance for that quarter.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, I found the answer. However, I cannot understand the formula. isnt RATE/4 as it is quarterly compounded?

```
=PMT(RATE/12, NPER*12,,FV,1)
```